# SQL Server/Oracle/MySQL database tool for developers (DDL Manipulation, stored procedures, triggers, OLEDB, ADO.NET)

Tags: windows, linux, database, data-visualization, data-analysis

I'm looking for a Database tool for developers with the following features:

- SQL querying
- Can be connected to SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL.
- Can run on Windows and Linux distros
- DDL Manipulation (graphic interface to create/edit table/view definitions would be a plus, but no necessary)
- Create/edit stored procedures, triggers, etc a plus
- support for JDBC connections would be a plus
- support for OLEDB / ADO.NET data providers would be a plus

It doesn't matter (much) if it's free, open source or proprietary (as long as there is a sort of free trial to test before buying the corresponding license).

Does anyone know something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Eclipse with the [Eclipse Data Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/downloads.php):

- SQL querying (with a GUI to create create queries visually)
- Can be connected to SQL Server, Oracle and MySQL.
- Can run on Windows and Linux distros
- DDL Manipulation
- Create/edit stored procedures, triggers.
- support for JDBC connections

[image]

[image]

PS: [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad/) is Windows only but otherwise it is a great tool and has all the features you asked for (except OLEDB / ADO.NET for which I am unsure).

Answer (score 2):

I use [Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com/products.dbw.index.php) under Windows.

It's paid, but there is a [free edition](http://www.upscene.com/products.dbw.index.php#sthash.6V3KBFTq.dpuf) that supports a single database system (currently InterBase, Firebird or MySQL) and a basic set of features ([feature matrix](http://www.upscene.com/products.dbw.featurematrix.php))

Features e.g.

- Data Model Design (Reverse engineer existing databases to print graphical overviews, use sub-diagrams)
- Visual Editors
- Stored Routine Debugging (Stored Procedures, Stored Functions, Packages and Triggers)
- Two-Way Visual Query Builder
- SQL and Parameter Insight
- Code and SQL Catalogs
- Object and Code Templates
- Drag and Drop Objects
- Database Compare and Migration (Migrate meta data structures from one database system to another)
- Transfer, import and export data (even any ODBC or ADO data source)
- Unicode enabled

Some screenshots from the free Firebird version:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jan! A new major version was released last August ( http://www.upscene.com/database_workbench/whatsnew ) and several of our users use the product under Linux using Wine ( see http://www.upscene.com/company/support )

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try [0xDBE](http://www.jetbrains.com/dbe/) from JetBrains. It's early access but looks like quite handy tool. It supports many DB engines: Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, H2, Apache Derby, Sybase, DB2, SQLite, SQLServer and few others.

Main features:

1. Code Completion
2. Renaming and Finding Usages
3. Code Analysis and Quick-fixes
4. Powerful Editor
5. Code Formatting
6. Slick Table Editor
7. Navigation
8. Managing Schema

Full overview [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/dbe/features/)